# Producing multiple buttons using a for loop and being able to differentiate between them and run separate code on mouse click.

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am trying to create a function that automatically creates 10 buttons using a for loop and positions them on screen and name them 1 to 10. Then when pressed a parameter that was passed during their creation instructs another function which button was pressed and adds different items to a list.

```
def button_placement():
    mover = 227
    button_number = 1
    for items in range(10):
        button_number = IntVar()
        Button(canvas1, width="5", height="2", textvariable=button_number, 
        command= lambda: button_action(button_number)).place(x=150, y=mover)
        mover = mover + 50
        button_number = button_number +1
def button_action(button_identifier):
    global list2
    global list1
    for buttons in range(1,10):
        if button_identifier == buttons:
            if len(list1) > 1:
                list2.append(list1[buttons])
```

Where both list 1 and 2 have items in them already. And please excuse the global variables.At the moment something is wrong with the IntVar operand in button_placement. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `lambda` in this situation because it's late binding. Use `functools.partial` instead. Also, you don't need IntVar, use a normal python integer.

```
from functools import partial

def button_placement():
    mover = 227
    for button_number in range(10):
        btn = Button(canvas1, width="5", height="2", text=button_number, 
            command= partial(button_action, button_number))
        btn.place(x=150, y=mover)
        mover = mover + 50
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer man, your code works perfectly for everything but it doesn't label the buttons 1 to 10?  I have never seen the partial function before so I don't know if there's some of way doing it with that? Thanks very much for the response though!

Comment: I made a ninja edit to change 'textvariable' to 'text', did you see that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're putting the `Button`s on a `Canvas`, nor exactly what you're trying to do with the two global `list`s—so I left them out and just made the `command` function `print()` what button identifier it's now being passed as an argument.

That said, here's a runnable example that shows how to pass extra arguments to the `Button`'s command handler function by defining it to have a default argument with the desired value in it when declaring the `lambda` function.

While this can also be done using `partial` as described in [@Novel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50360987/355230), but this approach is probably the more common way it's done—and is more concise than using `functools`. Either way, you don't need to use an `IntVar` to accomplish what you want since you'll effectively be passing the value to the function now.

```
from tkinter import *

def button_placement(canvas):
    xpos, ypos = 150, 25
    for button_number in range(1, 11):
        button = Button(canvas, width='5', height='2', text=button_number,
                    anchor=CENTER, command=
                    lambda id=button_number: button_action(id))
        window = canvas.create_window(xpos, ypos, window=button)
        ypos += 50

def button_action(button_identifier):
    print('Button {} pressed'.format(button_identifier))

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, height=500)
button_placement(canvas)
canvas.pack()
canvas.mainloop()
```

Here's what it looks like running on my Windows system:

[image: screenshot showing buttons]